# how to send array data to next page AngularJS/HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on AngularJS, I want to send this arrayServices to next page,

This array contains few documents, please help me ?

```
var arrayServices =[{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5931827befa50b137477a136"), 
    "parent" : ObjectId("59318060efa50b137477a130"), 
    "name" : "Teinture Cils", 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-06-02T15:21:31.199+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-06-02T15:21:31.199+0000"), 

}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5931828defa50b137477a137"), 
    "parent" : ObjectId("59318060efa50b137477a130"), 
    "name" : "Forfait Cils et Sourcils", 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-06-02T15:21:49.138+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-06-02T15:21:49.138+0000"), 

}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("593182a1efa50b137477a138"), 
    "parent" : ObjectId("593180b1efa50b137477a131"), 
    "name" : "Maquillage Mariée (Essai Maquillage + Maquillage)", 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-06-02T15:22:09.472+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-06-02T15:22:09.472+0000"), 

}]
```

Comment: If you need to share data across components it's almost always best to store it in a service.  (There aren't "pages" in an angular app, so any components that include the same service will get the same data.)

Comment: As Daniel mentioned, angular is intended for SPAs.  If you truly need to pass data between pages, and not components you'll have to look beyond angular, to a server based approach (e.g. session), a client asked approach (e.g. local cache), or some combination (cookie to re-inflate previous session), in order to convey the state.  That being said, there are angular components that will help manipulate these data stores on the client.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could code it out for me. Since I am quite juvenile to angularjs, I will get to learn how to send array between two controller

Comment: I can't really improve on the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use services.

Services are Singleton and are initialized only once, hence they are used to exchange data.

Eg:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var appCtrl = app.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

appCtrl.$inject = ['ShareDataService'];

function AppCtrl(ShareDataService){
  var appCtrl = this;
  appCtrl.variable = "search";

   appCtrl.setSearchQuery = function () {    
       ShareDataService.setSearchQuery(appCtrl.variable);
    }

    appCtrl.getSearchQuery = function () {    
        return ShareDataService.getSearchQuery();
    }   

}

var sharedDataService = app.service('ShareDataService',ShareData);

function ShareData(){
  var shareDataService = this;

  shareDataService.searchQuery = "";

  shareDataService.getSearchQuery = function(){
    return shareDataService.searchQuery;
  }

  shareDataService.setSearchQuery = function(searchQuery){
    shareDataService.searchQuery = searchQuery;
  }
}
```

In place of search query you can use your `arrayServices` and hence you can send data.